# WordPress and Windows IIS Server Problems

Tags: wordpress, iis

I am currently working on a WordPress project on a remote IIS server. I consider myself well versed in the use of WordPress, however, most of my previous projects have been on Apache servers and I am really running into problems on the IIS server.

I have contacted the host, and made sure that I have the correct file permissions. However, I cannot upload files or edit themes/plugins from the WordPress backend.

For example, when I use the WordPress theme editor panel, I make changes in the text, but when I click save there is no "Your changes have been saved message" and the file is just reverted to what it was before.

When I try to upload an image inside a post, I receive the following message:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to C:\xxx\wwwroot\xxx.com\www\dev/wp-content\uploads.

I notice the slash to the right of dev is incorrect, but I cannot figure out how to change this. I have tried defining this in the wp-config file with several different variations with no luck. For example, I have tried adding **define('UPLOADS', '\wp-content\uploads')** and I have also tried using the absolute path.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? I need to get this squared away as soon as possible, but I am not sure where to go from here. Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

.

.

.

**Edit**

I have tried altering the "upload_path" via wp-admin/options.php with no success, and the following results:

When I try the absolute path, **C:\xxx\wwwroot\xxx.com\www\dev\wp-content\uploads**, I get the following

> The uploaded file could not be moved to C:\xxx\wwwroot\xxx.com\www\dev\wp-content\uploads.

When I try **wp-content\uploads** in the "upload_path", I get the following

> The uploaded file could not be moved to C:\xxx\wwwroot\xxx.com\www\dev/wp-content\uploads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chris's Blog » Wordpress upload permissions on IIS 7 Fix](http://chris.wastedhalo.com/2011/01/wordpress-upload-permissions-on-iis-7-fix/) or Google for the IIS6 fix:

> ...You need to give the IUSR account Read/Write/Modify permission on
>   your wp-content folder.... and you need to give the IIS_IUSRS group
>   Read permissions on your “C:\Windows\Temp” folder.

See [10 Reasons Why Not to Host Your Wordpress Blog on a Windows/IIS Platform](http://www.thisishowyoudoit.com/blog/10-reasons-why-not-to-host-your-wordpress-blog-on-a-windowsiis-platform/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have contacted the host and am waiting to see if the permissions fixes listed in the article will help.  Thanks for the second article as well.  I will definitely use that link as reference the next time someone asks me to install WordPress on IIS, haha.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give php temp dir full permissions (iusr) (network service) c:\winnt\temp is the default upload dir before it moves to the wp site so this has to be set

in php admin (in iis applet) u can change the temp dir if your not liking the fact its in your NOS dir

next issue u will have is max_fileupload size also in php admin

iis works great best if your the admin of the server to quickly make the needed changes